# Applications missing after "fsck"

Tags: python

I had an error on booting which left [initramfs] on the screen, after checking using another computer I ran the fsck as recommended, itallowed me to use the recovery mode on rebooting.
However the Sofware updater, and others from the System menu will not run. I can update from the CLI.
I read it might be a Python missing file, but all I get is this:-

```
hal@hal-X550LA:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
hal@hal-X550LA:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 50, in <module>
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 50, in <module>
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'
```

I am running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on an ASUS X550LA laptop, most other "things" seem to be working, can anyone please help me sort this problem as I'm way out of my depth.
Hal.
Just some more information that may help clarify my problem.

```
hal@hal-X550LA:~$ sudo apt install python3.8
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Hal.

Comment: A *could not get lock* is usually caused because another process is running and trying to make changes, so I'd firstly check you don't have another terminal running where it's waiting for a response from you? (*happens to me semi-regularly*) or try again later (*you were unlucky as system was checking for updates etc*).  I would also add `python -V; python3 -V` output (two lines) to ensure you've not changed default python2/python3.

Comment: Thank you guiverc, I ran install Python again and now have 2.7.17 and 3.6.9. Still no response for most of the "System > Administration tools" such as Software updater, Software Boutique etc.

Comment: 3.6.9?  If you're using Bionic/18.04, it should report 3.6.7 as default (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3) which will mean any system tool that uses `python3` may not work as you've changed the version. You should revert your version change, restore backups & not change the default python (there are alternatives if you need a specific version of python for your own applications avoiding changing defaults).

Comment: Thank you again, I'll have a look at that once I work how to do it. Very much the novice here I'm afraid.